# Acquire annotation parameters (or annotation instance) from Kotlin PSI

Tags: kotlin, abstract-syntax-tree, detekt, intellij-platform-psi

I have a Kotlin annotation:

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
annotation class Type(
    val type: String
)
```

It can be used on the Kotlin classes in two ways: using the named parameter syntax, or using the positional parameter syntax:

```
@Type(type = "named")
data class Named(
    …
)

@Type("positional")
data class Positional
    …
)
```

I use this annotation in my custom [detekt](https://github.com/arturbosch/detekt) rules for some extra checks. I need to extract the value of the `type` parameter to perform some check based on it. I do that like:

```
private fun getType(klass: KtClass): String? {
    val annotation = klass
        .annotationEntries
        .find {
            "Type" == it?.shortName?.asString()
        }
    val type = (annotation
        ?.valueArguments
        ?.find {
            it.getArgumentName()?.asName?.asString() == "type"
        }
        ?.getArgumentExpression() as? KtStringTemplateExpression)
        ?.takeUnless { it.hasInterpolation() }
        ?.plainContent

    return type
}
```

But this code works only with "named" parameters syntax, and fails for the positional one. Is there any way to get the value of an annotation parameter no matter what syntax was used? It would be perfect if I could acquire my `Type` annotation instance directly from PSI / AST / `KtElement`s and use it like usually. Is it possible to instantiate an annotation from the PSI tree?

Comment: Have you figured out a solution for this? Please update. Many thanks

Comment: @MohamedAouledIssa, unfortunately, no. The question is still open.

Comment: @madhead Can you check code with PSIviewer plugin? So you will get how elements organized, what is the type.

Comment: @Godwin, I have this plugin installed. It doesn't help in this case.